# Select query not giving me values

Tags: php, select

Ok I am using the following code to send an email with some details to the users of my hypothetical website.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ads WHERE type="Offer" AND category ="' 
.$_POST['category']. '" AND details LIKE "%'.$_POST['details']. 
'%"';

 $r = mysqli_query ($conn, $sql);

 $maxMails = 3;
$count = 0;

while ($r && $d = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r) && $count < $maxMails) {

  $to      = mysqli_fetch_array ($conn->query ('SELECT email FROM publishers WHERE login_name="'. $_COOKIE ['user_username']. '"'), MYSQLI_ASSOC)['email'];
  $subject = 'New ad that may interest you';
  $message = 'Type: '.$d['type']."\r\n".'Category: '.$d['category']."\r\n".'Details: ' .$d['details'];

  mail($to, $subject, $message);

  $count++;
}
```

But none of the `$d ['nameOfVariable']` gives any value in the mail. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please be aware that you should **NEVER** use `$_POST` (or equivalent variables) directly in SQL statements! You should use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead, binding your `$_POST` variables to parameters. Given your code above, you have a serious security vulnerability -- a malicious user could easily `DROP` your entire database (or possibly even create a backdoor). You can refer to [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) for further information on how to prevent SQL injection in PHP :)

Comment: Oh ok thanx! :D

Comment: You don't need to do the second query every time through the loop. It fetches the same email each time, so just do it once.

Comment: What does `var_dump($d)` show?

Comment: I suspect the problem is that the column names have uppercase letters, so maybe it should be `$d['Type']` rather than `$d['type']`.

Comment: If you only want to send 3 emails, use `LIMIT 3` in the query rather than doing `$count < $maxMails` in the loop.

Comment: Yeah I've done all the corrections, there was a problem with the `$count < $maxMails` condition in the if clause, as soon as I removed it everything works fine :D